# Does this strategy of characterizing poles always work?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity, meromorphic-functions

I stumbled upon a fast way to characterize poles of order $m$ of a meromorphic function $f$ (on some open set $\Omega$) in this [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/380593/453441). My question is, does this general strategy always work?

Here's why I think it doesn't always work. Consider 
$$f(z) = \frac{\cos z -1}{z^2}.$$
According to the general strategy given in the answer, $z = 0$ should be a simple pole (pole of order $1$) as $0$ is a root of $z^2$ of multiplicity $2$ and $0$ is a root of $\cos z - 1$ of multiplicity $1$. Therefore, $0$ is a pole of order $2-1 = 1$.

But then, considering the power series expansion of $\cos z$, we have
$$f(z) = -\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{z^2}{4!} - \frac{z^4}{6!} + \ldots$$
So evidently we see here that $z= 0$ is a removable singularity of $f(z)$.

Is there a flaw in how I used the answerer's argument or it is thus true that the general strategy does not always work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that $0$ is a root of $\cos(z)-1$ of multiplicity $2$, not $1$.

Comment: Wait I think I may have misunderstood things here. Is "a zero of multiplicity $k$" the same thing as "a zero of order $k$"?

Comment: Yes, I just used "multiplicity" because you did, it's more commonly used for polynomials.

Comment: I see! So the notion of order is a generalization of this.